# Get data from event object

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, dom-events

I have a custom type like this, called `Message`:

```
Message message = new Message("string1, "string2", "string3");
```

And I emit it to my Node.Js server like this:

```
socket.emit('event', message);
```

Is it possible to extract the Strings from my Object in my Node.Js function?

```
socket.on('event', (message) => {
 //extract the Strings from the Message object
});
```

Before I have always sent the parameters seperately but I was wondering if it is possible to do it like this, only send an object and decompose it on my server side

Edit:
Message Constructor:

```
public String String1, String2, String3;

public Message(String string1, String string2, String string3) {
    String1 = string1;
    String2 = string2;
    String3 = string3;
}
```

Comment: If you `console.log` that message server-side, what output do you get?

Comment: It depends on `Message` object. Can you post at least constructor from `Message` object

Comment: @rustyshackleford my server logs just give me `[object Object]` back

Comment: @Darius sure I added it! But it‘s only a simple constructor, nothing really special about it as far as I thought

Comment: It should be `message.String1`.... In such situations easiest way: make breakpoint in event and check variables. If you use without developement tool: `console.log(JSON.stringify(message))`. In such cases it depends on used framework and behavior of serializers. The best is to check documentation of used framework, as you didn't mention what you use.

Comment: @Darius That‘s a good advice, I wasn‘t even thinking about that! Also your solution works fine, it‘s easily accessible by `message.String1`, just as you said. Thank you very much for your help! If you formulated it into an answer, I‘d gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on used framework and behavior of serializer. The best way is to check documentation of used framework as you didn't mention which one you use.

Acording to `Message` object structure, message members should be:
`message.String1`, `message.String2`, ...

In such situations easiest way is to make breakpoint in event and check object content. If you do not use developement tool for node.js: `console.log(JSON.stringify(message))`.